# Log a message send to nil?

Tags: objective-c, logging

I know that messaging `nil` is not an error, and generally it's not an issue, but at times it would be nice to see a warning logged to the console when it happens.

Comment: Why the close... you should be required to commend why.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would that be interesting?

Comment: It was a lot more useful back when [nil methodReturningFloat] or [nil methodReturningStruct] would return garbage instead of 0s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[You could, once upon a time.](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2008/01/02/objective-c-logging-messages-to-nil/) I don't know if it still works, or if it ever worked on iOS.

Comment: The DTrace idea/script in the comments also looks promising.

Comment: This can't work on iOS (see objc_msgSend() in http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/Messengers.subproj/objc-msg-arm.s). It should work on the simulator, however (see http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/Messengers.subproj/objc-msg-simulator-i386.s)