# Warning about nil receiver

Tags: objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to log a message send to nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9883599/is-there-any-way-to-log-a-message-send-to-nil)

I wonder if there any possibility to log when nil object accessed? Similar to "Enable Zombie Objects", but for nil.